# How to create a C/C++ Library and Put them into Xcode for iOS?

Tags: c++, ios, c, xcode

I have lots of useful platform independent code made in C/C++ such as string/number/private data management, etc.

Now, as a starter to programming to iOS, I want to re-use the library for my project.

I don't think I can use it directly, but before starting, I want to check, but not easy to find the answer at this time.

What I want is

1. Implement a C++ library with public header files for iOS (not MacOSX) in Xcode.
2. Build them and get libProject.dynamic / libProject.a / other header files.
3. Integrate them into Xcode so that other separate client app (object-c) can use it.

If someone help me brief introduction how to achieve above or any other reference would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Hana

Comment: there is no special work need to be done just because they are C++ code not ObjC code

Comment: I'm thinking I will add a thin CoreFoundation Framework layer in the library. For example, if I want to work with a string, I will add a CFStringRef and it can be used in NSString as toll-free bridge.

Comment: so? you know how to add framework right?

Comment: Yes, I know how to add it. And, what I don't know is how to build and get the library output/headers and how put them into Xcode. When I build it, I got "Check dependencies target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.library.dynamic', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform" When I compile it for MacOSX, no compile error.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode, you can simply choose "New Project" from the "File" menu, and from the project template chooser, click on "Framework & Library" under the "iOS" section. There is a single entry - "Cocoa Touch Static Library". Use that as your Xcode project template to make the static library. Then you can include it in your other projects just like you would any other static library.